# How to update individual nested dictionary once per iteration

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I need to update a single nested dictionary at once.

I have a for loop where ***rows*** is a NodeList (minidom)

Where dictKeys looks like this :

```
dictKeys = {'LastEditDate': {}, 'LastEditorUserId': {}, 'LastActivityDate': {}, 'Id': {}, 'CommentCount': {}, 'ParentId': {}, 'CreationDate': {}, 'Title': {}, 'PostTypeId': {}, 'AnswerCount': {}, 'ClosedDate': {}, 'OwnerUserId': {}, 'ViewCount': {}, 'Body': {}, 'Score': {}, 'AcceptedAnswerId': {}, 'OwnerDisplayName': {}, 'Tags': {}, 'FavoriteCount': {}}

for index,element in enumerate(rows):
    for key in dictKeys.keys():
        dictKeys[key][index] = ""
    for attrName, attrValue in element.attributes.items():
        dictKeys[attrName][index]= attrValue
```

Instead of each key value pair updating on each iteration, they're all updating at once.

```
{'LastEditDate': {0: '11062'}, 'LastEditorUserId': {0: '11062'}, 'LastActivityDate': {0: '11062'}, 'Id': {0: '11062'}, 'CommentCount': {0: '11062'}, 'ParentId': {0: '11062'}, 'CreationDate': {0: '11062'}, 'Title': {0: '11062'}, 'PostTypeId': {0: '11062'}, 'AnswerCount': {0: '11062'}, 'ClosedDate': {0: '11062'}, 'OwnerUserId': {0: '11062'}, 'ViewCount': {0: '11062'}, 'Body': {0: '11062'}, 'Score': {0: '11062'}, 'AcceptedAnswerId': {0: '11062'}, 'OwnerDisplayName': {0: '11062'}, 'Tags': {0: '11062'}, 'FavoriteCount': {0: '11062'}}
```

and

```
{'LastEditDate': {0: '2'}, 'LastEditorUserId': {0: '2'}, 'LastActivityDate': {0: '2'}, 'Id': {0: '2'}, 'CommentCount': {0: '2'}, 'ParentId': {0: '2'}, 'CreationDate': {0: '2'}, 'Title': {0: '2'}, 'PostTypeId': {0: '2'}, 'AnswerCount': {0: '2'}, 'ClosedDate': {0: '2'}, 'OwnerUserId': {0: '2'}, 'ViewCount': {0: '2'}, 'Body': {0: '2'}, 'Score': {0: '2'}, 'AcceptedAnswerId': {0: '2'}, 'OwnerDisplayName': {0: '2'}, 'Tags': {0: '2'}, 'FavoriteCount': {0: '2'}}
```

I am wondering how to do this properly?

Comment: can you add the value of rows and also your expected output?

Comment: This is not really a duplicate, and I'm not sure I understand your question, but see if https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1663807/how-to-iterate-through-two-lists-in-parallel helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have an empty dictionary

```
d = {}
```

and use it as an initial item value

```
dictKeys = {'a': d, 'b': d, 'c': d}
```

then a single dictionary `d` still exists, referenced from all places.

Even though you update a single item

```
dictKeys['a'][0] = 'hello'
```

this update seemingly occurs everywhere.

```
assert dictKeys == {'a': {0: 'hello'}, 'b': {0: 'hello'}, 'c': {0: 'hello'}}
```

Comment: I understand, but now I am wondering why would dictKeys = {'a': {}, 'b': {}, 'c': {}} use the same dictionary referenced from all places? Would I really have to create 18 different variables? There has to be a better way to initialize a new dictionary.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this behaviour in Python 3.7.5. Do you use an older version?

Comment: the function I was using to create my dictionary was initializing from a single instance. That's why I was producing the behavior.